# How to find the start and end duration of "Selected frames" from Video using didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I am doing **slow motion** in audio and video using **AVFoundation**(for Video) and **Dirac**(Audio).
As part of it, i will show the video as frames in which the user will select the frames to do slow motion. Eg: 5-6 min of 10 min video.

I have to show the users two kinds of videos 1. through the video recorder from my application itself. 2. from the gallery.

**Case1: No problem**
Now,i can record the videos though my video recorder and show the videos as frames to the user to select. Once the user selects some frames(Eg: 5 to 6 min of 10 min recorded video), 
using the below code, i am able to find the **start/end duration** of the selected frames or video.

```
NSNumber *start = [info objectForKey:@"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart"];
NSNumber *end = [info objectForKey:@"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd"];

int startMilliseconds = ([start doubleValue] * 1000);
int endMilliseconds = ([end doubleValue] * 1000);
```

**Case2:**
 In this case, i am able to pick the video from the gallery and show them to the user in the form of frames to select. However, when i try to find the start/end duration of the video as **i did in case 1 with the same code, its not working**. I am always getting **"0"** for start/end duration.

Comment: can please let me know if there any suggestions ?

Comment: So you are saying that:
1. If you get the video from your own video recorder, you can access the start/end duration time.
2. If you get a video from the user's gallery, it returns 0 for start/end duration?

In case 2, do you enable editing? (videoRecorder.allowsEditing = YES;)

Comment: Yes i enabled editing. Please check my output here : http://pastebin.com/wiHiuPXZ . Here i'm not able to get the property "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd" and "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart" using user's photo gallery but for own video recording it returns the output.

Comment: Unless there is something wrong with how you are getting the video out of the user's gallery, this approach should work fine.  Are you getting the video and trimming as described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439707/how-to-trim-the-video-using-avfoundation

Comment: yeah, which @Chris Truman provide that link/above link is working fine for me not exactly your requirment. 2vision2 pls check it once..

Comment: I have tried but still i'm not able to get the value in photo gallery for _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart . Here's my code in the link : http://pastebin.com/tmD1bXJe can you please guide me what's wrong in that .? i have tried many ways but i'm not able to get the trim start and end value in Photo's gallery. .

Comment: @ chris tuman can you give some solution ?

Comment: Sorry @2vision2 I can't see why this code isn't working.  Seems like it may be some weird bug like the video being deallocated or no trim was selected.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/achingbrain/slowdown

Comment: also take a look at http://kineme.net/forum/Programming/SelectableVideoInput

Comment: did you set     UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
.............. mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate; CHeck here how it merge video frame time http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Comment: Yes can you please check my code here : http://pastebin.com/tmD1bXJe

Comment: please check the edited answer...hope it will work for you surely...

Comment: @ iphonemaclover - Please check my question, In Case 1 it's working fine and in Case 2 it's not working. For better understanding check the screen shot here : http://pbrd.co/18ThIMI , trim start and end time returns 0 while picking the pick the video from the gallery.

Comment: print integer value in more places of print its taking as double or long value so we get exact milliseconds... cause of int and print it in console as %d show only one place value

Comment: long long milliseconds = (long long)([start doubleValue] * 1000);
then print it in console and check

Comment: @ iphonemaclover I'm not getting the Value in the (NSDictionary *) info for _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd . Please check my info here : http://pastebin.com/wiHiuPXZ . It's apple bug or is there some trick to solve this ? please help to resolve this ? I'm stuck up with this issue for past one month .

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266681/how-to-import-video-from-iphone-library-and-play-in-application

Comment: @iphonemaclover yes i checked. . I can able to get the moviepath in UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL. . But couldn't get the parameters _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart while picking video from gallery.

Comment: did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266681/how-to-import-video-from-iphone-library-and-play-in-application

Comment: @ iphonemaclover Yes i have checked but it's not helpful. . I have followed the steps give in the link. My problem is i'm not able to get the parameter _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd and _UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart in info(NSDictonary).. Fetching the trim and original video from (UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL and UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL)  is not a problem for me. . I hope you understand .

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new additions in AVFoundation in iOS 7 as it now natively supports slow motion video and audio auto-time stretching. This might change your approach, and a better solution.